# chrome no text showing when started in debug from VSCode on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

When Chrome starts in debug mode from VSCode not text is displayed. When Chrome is started from from the normal the normal link it displays the site correctly. When the developer tools in Chrome is opened no text is displayed.
Situation occurs since last week.

Google Chrome is up-to-date
Versie 67.0.3396.87 (Officiële build) (64-bits)

I have tried to clear caches and even reinstalled Chrome, but until now no succes.

[Image of fault situation Chrome launched from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZOtA.png)
[Image of desired situation Chrome started normally on same machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPqcG.png)

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to completely uninstall and reinstall Chrome and it didn't solve anything

Comment: I have the same issue. That's really annoying.